# Django - POST dynamically a list of dictionaries or dictionary on its own (NOT WORKING)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a Class Based View that inherits from ApiView with a get and post function. I wrote a custom mixin to add the functionality for the post request to accept both a list of objects and also a single object. When I make the class inherit the mixin nothing happens

```
class CreateListModelMixin:

    def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ if an array is passed, set serializer to many """
        if isinstance(kwargs.get('data', {}), list):
            kwargs['many'] = True
        return super(CreateListModelMixin, self).get_serializer(*args, **kwargs)

class User_ListView(CreateListModelMixin, APIView):
    def get(self):
        db_data = User.objects.all().prefetch_related("installation_mast")
        serializer = User_Serializer(db_data, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = User_Serializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

The get_serializer method of the mixin is not being called.
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

APIView does not have the get_serializer method, hence it cannot be overridden. To fix this you need to set use the GenericAPIView, set the serializer class and use the get_serializer() function to get the serializer in your post method. A working code is mentioned below

```
class CreateListModelMixin:

    def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ if an array is passed, set serializer to many """
        if isinstance(kwargs.get('data', {}), list):
            kwargs['many'] = True
        return super(CreateListModelMixin, self).get_serializer(*args, **kwargs)

class User_ListView(CreateListModelMixin, GenericAPIView):
    permission_classes = [DjangoCustomModelPermissions]
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = User_Serializer

    def get(self):
        db_data = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(db_data, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

This successfully is able to dynamically POST requests if they are a dictionary or a list of dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

In DRF APIView's interface, get_serializer method is never used. Even if it was used, the code above wouldn't work because of "Method Resolution Order" in Python.

In Python, "Method Resolution Order" is from left to right. So when you are inheriting a mixin class you should be writing it to left of the class that you'd like to override.

Note:
If you want to get use of "get_serializer" method being called then you may want to have a look at ModelViewSets (for official docs: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset)

Comment: Thanks! I do not want to use modelViewSet as this is a part of a larger application and I would not be able to use that. Is there any other way to do this with ApiView itself so that the post method can automatically detect that a list is passed in the request and add the many=True parameter to the serializer

Comment: The feature you're mentioning is coming from GenericApiView. You could explicitly inherit mixins that you use if you're not willing to use ModelSerializer.
docs: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#custom-viewset-base-classes @dracarys

Comment: @KutyAslan I tried to do it with the GenericApiView but it still does not work. I have updated the code in the question.